# PHP preg_match_all: brackets tags inside brackets tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have my custom tags, for ex.

```
{{tag-name}}
<table>
  <tr>
    {{loop}}<td>text</td> ... {{/loop}}
  </tr>
</table>
{{/tag-name}}
```

I want to extract HTML code inside bracket tags.

I use this pattern in preg_match_all:

```
/{\{.*?\}\}((?:(?!\{\{/(.*?)\}\}).)*)\{\{\/.*?\}\}/s
```

but it doesn't work. How can I fix this?

Comment: What should the extracted text look like?

Comment: Do you want to perform a replacement after with the matched content? I ask that because if yes, the approach may be different.

Comment: **What does "doesn't work" mean?** "Doesn't work" is an inadequate description for us to understand the problem.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get an error message?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Comment: @sshashank124, like that: http://pastebin.com/whJ2dnMh

Comment: @AndyLester, here's what I get: http://regex101.com/r/nX2tY2

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, when preg_match_all will found tag inside tag, I want to replace it by php loop.

Comment: PLEASE, don't parse html with regexp! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get your father's tags with preg_match_all and `"/\{\{.[^\}]+\}\}(.+)\{\{\/.+\}\}/s"` regex;
the problem is your tag inside another tag.

Look DomDocument at http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php is to easy to load your document, get tags inside document, and tags content, with a simple method call...

Answer (score 1):

If the `{{tag-name}}` is not arbitrary nested, this regex should do it:

```
$pattern = '~{{([^}]+)}}(.*?){{/\1}}~s';
```

[See on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/sY6aS7)

Captures the tag-name in first parenthesised group `{{([^}]+)}}` and matches the end `{{/\1}}`

Captured matches of 2nd parenthesised group `(.*?)` will be in `$out[2]`

Using `s (PCRE_DOTALL)` [modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) and `*?` [lazy quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

---

Use with [preg_match](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) or [preg_match_all](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) if desired, e.g.

```
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $input, $out)) {
   var_dump($out);
}
```

See [eval.in for an example](https://eval.in/135595).